# Problem with FatSecret's REST API

Tags: api

[FatSecret](http://www.fatsecret.com/) provides two APIs, one javascript and another a REST one. Because the javascript API is limited, I had to start with the REST API. They have an Oauth Scheme going. So, I took my parameters and created a signature, attached it to the url, made an ajax request and Voila! it doesn't work. I keep getting an invalid signature error response. I'm using the following parameters(along with a method to be called and response format) both to create a base string to be used for signature generation and to hit the actual API.

```
oauth_consumer_key: "MY_KEY"
oauth_nonce: "ABC"
oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_timestamp: "TIME",
oauth_version: "1.0",
oauth_signature: "WXYZ"
```

I am using a jquery UUID plugin to generate auth_nonce. I don't know what I am doing wrong but I'm fully sure that the signature I am generating is correct.

There is a rubygem that uses an Net::HTTP request which works totally fine. Even when I use the URL that the gem generates, I can't have any success with the jsonp request. But, if I use that URL on the browser(before the oauth_timestamp expires), it works totally fine.

I'll post more details if anyone is going to be interested.

The authentication documentation is available [here](http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=rapiauth).

Comment: I'd be interested to know if you managed to resolve this - working on integrating in ObjC and having a similar issue.

Comment: I got the authentication all right later, magically. But, I couldn't make cross domain requests.

Comment: I found out that I was doing the authentication all right. But, I couldn't make cross domain requests, fatsecret has no jsonp support and since javascript was my only programming option, there was no way out. I realize that I was trying to work with REST API via ajax while there was already a javascript API available. What's your problem?

Comment: Ah, mine was more directly related to OAuth - little harder to run the JavaScript API on iOS! Mine was related to the majority of implementations of OAuth on iOS being based around Twitter's implementation, which is subtly different to FatSecret's.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having a tough time getting this API to work for me as well.

This [test OAuth test client](http://term.ie/oauth/example/client.php) has helped me to sort out my OAuth errors.

Remember that parameters are sorted using lexicographical byte value ordering, first by name and then by value.

lexicographical example that works in this case:

1. oauth_alpha=first
2. oauth_batman=second (#2 because of "b" in batman)
3. oauth_beta=third (#3 because of "e" in beta)
4. oauth_beta=zebra (#4 because of "z" in in zebra)

Comment: 'lexicographical byte value ordering, first by name and then by value.' - WTF is that supposed to mean :/ Sorry, just venting my frustration: it's been 2 hours and i still can't get it to work

Comment: I edited the answer to give an example of the ordering that works in this case.